# What is an example of a windows shell command that requires elevated privileges to run?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I want to see what resources are available to my application's embedded Lua VM via the `os.execute` functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo text > c:\foo.txt`

Non-privileged users can't create files on the system's drive root (as well as other system folders). Just one example out of many possible...

You can also try to run regedit.exe. As a regular user, you'll be denied.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks